# how to show to do lists and images specific to user utilizing current_user helper from devise for RoR projects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm creating a simple project management tool w/ to do lists and image uploads. Currently having an issue where I can't figure out how to display only the current logged in user's to do lists and images. I've tried the below in my dashboard controller:

```
class DashboardsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @todo_lists = @user.TodoList.all
    #@todo_lists = TodoList.find(:all, :conditions => { :user_id => current_user[:id] } )
    #@todo_list = current_user.TodoList.find(params[:id])
    #@todo_lists = TodoList.find_all_by_user_id current_user[:id]
    #@todo_lists = TodoList.all
    @paperclip_image = PaperclipImage.last 
  end
end
```

I keep getting a no method errors: NoMethodError in DashboardsController#index
undefined method `TodoList' for #. How would you display just items specific to the logged in user? I have user ids successfully assigned to each to do list and image upload in my dev DB.

installed gem versions:

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.1'
gem 'devise'
```

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a properly configured :has_many association from user to todo_lists it should just be

```
current_user.todo_lists
```

Has Many Association

```
 class User < Active::Record
   has_many :todo_lists
 end

 class TodoList < Active::Record
   belongs_to :user
 end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't have the associations in my user model.